# Hooking a Swift method with frida on iOS to inspect DSA signing arguments

Tags: ios, frida, swift, cryptokit

I have an iOS app that is sending a DSA signature with certain requests. Initially, I  would just like to be able to hook the method performing the signing and dump the arguments.

In ghidra, I can see that it is importing the following from CryptoKit:

```
$s9CryptoKit4P256O7SigningO14ECDSASignatureVMa
$s9CryptoKit13SecureEnclaveO4P256O7SigningO10PrivateKeyV9signature3forAaDOAFO14ECDSASignatureVx_tKAA6DigestRzlF
$s9CryptoKit4P256O7SigningO14ECDSASignatureV17derRepresentation10Foundation4DataVvg
```

In frida I can use the following script which will find those symbols and then successfully log when they are called in the `onenter`:

```
var imports = Module.enumerateImportsSync("AppName").filter(item => item.module.toLowerCase().includes("cryptokit")).filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().includes("dsa"));
imports.forEach(function(value) {
  Interceptor.attach(value.address, {
    onEnter(args) {
      console.log("[+] " + value.name + " called.");
    }
  });
});
```

The problem I have is if I try and access an argument passed to the function. [This](https://learnfrida.info/macos/#getting-cryptokits-aesgcmseal-data-before-encryption) was the closest example I could find but wasn't sure if the Swift calling convention was similar to Objective-C in terms of the first two arguments being self and cmd. Assuming that there was at least one argument though, if I simply added `var firstArgument = args[0];` in `onEnter`, the app would just hang, and even exiting frida wouldn't prompt it to resume.

I looked at frida's Swift [documentation](https://github.com/frida/frida-swift-bridge/blob/main/docs/api.md) and tried to use `Swift.Interceptor.attach`. This would also happily attach to the symbols found and log that they were called. If I tried to do `var test = new Swift.Objec(args[0])` for any of those symbols found I would get an error `Couldn't parse function with signature: type metadata accessor for CryptoKit.P256.Signing.ECDSASignature`.